# How to Pass localstorage from cordova app to use form Siri Shortcuts

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, sirishortcuts, siri-intent

I have a native ios and android application created using Corodova + Vue. how it works is once i compile the code it builds both platforms (ios and android). so if i want to change something in the app i have to maek changes in cordova and vue native app.

now i want to add siri shortcuts for my app. and i started to build it in swift code (i opened the the project from the platform created by cordova). In swift i created Intent and every basic things need to create a siri shortcut. But i am not stuck at making post request. How my post request works is i have to pass a localid (user ID) in the body of the post request and it get all the info about the user. For the cordova app the localid is stored in Localstorage and i cannot access the localstorage using the swift code. anyway we can create a bridge to access localstorage from native app to swift code?